# What could cause GCP Cloud Run to respond 10-30% slower than the same service running in Kubernetes (GKE)?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

I have a web service running in GKE behind a GCP global HTTPS load balancer. The same code is also deployed to Cloud Run. The load balancer splits traffic 50-50 between GKE and Cloud Run. According to the load balancer, the total latency from Cloud Run is about 10 to 30% higher than it is from GKE.

[image: Top line is Cloud Run average latency, bottom line is GKE average latency]
*https/total_latencies, top line is Cloud Run average latency, bottom line is GKE average latency*

The same code is deployed to both environments in the same region. The service does not have any dependencies on databases. It does make HTTP requests over the public internet, which makes it unlikely that the requests from GKE are getting routed differently than the ones in Cloud Run. There's a clear difference in latency between Cloud Run and GKE regardless of HTTP status code class, whether it's 2xx, 3xx, 4xx, or 5xx. There's also consistently a gap, indicating the issue is not due to cold starts.

To try to eliminate the possibility that the Cloud Run instances are overburdened, they are given more vCPU cores and memory than the GKE pods. The target number of concurrent requests is also set much lower than the target request rate used by the GKE service's HPA. In short, the Cloud Run instances are given many more resources than the GKE pods.

Based on the symptoms, it appears there could be a systemic source of latency from Cloud Run. The only other metric that shows a difference between Cloud Run and GKE is the load balancer's `https/backend_request_bytes_count` metric, which is 2-3x higher for Cloud Run (about 1.2 KB for GKE and 3.1 KB for Cloud Run), which is difficult to explain because the service receives only GET requests, so there's unlikely to be a difference in request size from clients until the load balancer is adding 1.9 KB worth of headers when connecting to Cloud Run.
[image: Backend request bytes]
*https/backend_request_bytes_count, top line is Cloud Run, bottom line is GKE*
Setting up a TLS connection is the only overhead that comes to mind, if the Google Cloud load balancer weren't reusing HTTP connections.

In summary, are there systemic reasons that Google Cloud Run's infrastructure would be slower than GKE's and why would the request size between a Google Cloud load balancer and Cloud Run be 2-3x larger than requests between the same load balancer and GKE?

Comment: I'm curious if you have tried this with Cloud Run new execution environment.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-execution-environments

It notes that it will have a faster network performance.

Comment: Have you run your tests w/o using the GCLB and just using the default end point for the Cloud Run service? I know that's not what you desire, but might show that the latency is actually caused by the GCLB interaction and not Cloud Run itself.

Comment: Try multi-region load balancing, it is supported only for [serverless NEGs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless) with Cloud Run backends. You might need to serve your Cloud Run app from more than one region to improve end-user latency.

Comment: @cvu proposal is great. I'm interesting to know the difference with non sandboxed environment.

Comment: Cloud Run automatically scales to 0 if no requests come in. Then containers needs to restart. Did you specified a min number of instances to keep alive?

Comment: The second generation GCR environment with non-zero minimum instances didn't make a noticeable change over several hours. A clear difference between GKE and GCR is GKE backends receive "http:" URLs while GCR backends receive "https:" URLs. It's not clear whether GCLB is using keep-alive connections when connecting to GCR and what the overhead of the TLS handshake and encrypting each packet is. Changing the application code to use unsecured HTTP/2 with GCR (the only GCR networking option available) is one of my few ideas left right now, so hoping that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use an Ubuntu-based image instead of an Alpine-based one. Specifically, switching from Node.js's Alpine images to their default images, for the same version of Node.js, resolved the performance gap. In contrast, adjusting the settings provided by Cloud Run like the execution environment and minimum instances did not make a difference in this scenario.